# Running Matlab Code from dot net

Tags: .net, matlab, matlab-compiler

I've compiled a little program using matlab 2013
I can see in my dll:
`Test.TestMethods`  all my functions

I've added it as a reference to my dot net project, and added the `MWArray` dll from matlab bin\win64\v2.0 folder.

** Update: The app crushes at this line in the matlabe generated code:

```
mcr= new MWMCR("", ctfFilePath, embeddedCtfStream, true);
```

If I embed the ctf file - it will crush, if I don't embed it, it will throw an exception.

I've set my program to build against X64.

Once I try to create the object:

```
Test.TestMethods test = new Test.TestMethods();
```

My App crashes. 
I can only see in external Visual Studio instance:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0000000001D36E60 (m_interpreter.dll). 
Access violation reading location 0x00000000A5CE3920.
```

I have no idea where to start....

EDIT1: this is the ctor (there is also a static cctor):

```
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       20 (0x14)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Exception Test.TestMethods::ex_
  IL_000b:  brfalse.s  IL_0013
  IL_000d:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Exception Test.TestMethods::ex_
  IL_0012:  throw
  IL_0013:  ret
} // end of method TestMethods::.ctor
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague. What is `Test.TestMethods`? Is `MWArray` a managed dll or native? How are you calling into `MWArray`? Can you post the code from `TestMethods`s' constructor?

Comment: this is a generated function by the matlab compiler. I can try to ildisasmble it..

Comment: Hmm well just make sure you've copied over ALL dependencies into your current working directory (eg. `MWArray` might have a dependency on one of the other dlls present in the matlab folder). Try copying over all the dlls and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried the TestNative Dll as well. Same thing.

Comment: <offtopic>Have you tried http://ilnumerics.net? I never touched the whole Matlab compiler thing again and use only pure managed code since then. little reason to continue to torture yourself ... just my 2C</offtopic>

Comment: Checking, but i hope to be able to run matlab from dot net... it can't be that difficult.

Comment: Dont know whether that applies to you.. in a project I am aware of, the problem is that dependencies need to be created when starting an app for the first time (you will see a generated subfolder), for the second run from same folder, everything is fine. (In the end, it looks like MCR is a lot of hassle. Still no solution for that problem.)

Comment: Yep, generated folder with _mcr suffix is created. But application is still crashing during a MCR initialization: new MWMCR(..) with an access violation error inside m_interpreter.dll

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call MATLAB generated .NET libraries from .NET 4.5 assemblies, also it crashes when VS debugger is attached.

Comment: My application is targeted for .NET framework v4.6.1 and it crashes exactly at the point where a new object for the class exported by MATLAB, is instantiated. Once I moved down to .NET framework v4.0, it worked.